# Test & Feedback Version : 1.0.121.0 Extension, Capture Screenshot Shortcut

Tags: azure-devops

Just Downloaded TFS 2017 and added Test & Feedback Version :    1.0.121.0     Extension for Chrome. I downloaded this extension to use for testing and screen capture. In previous Client Version the user can select (Ctrl+Windows+C) to do a screen capture, is there any way to configure a short cut using this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ctrl+Windows+C shortcut doesn’t work for me too. There is a user voice that you can vote: [Shortcut for Test & Feedback](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20482015-shortcut-for-test-feedback).

Comment: Thank you  I posted the request!